# How to change the "Date" and "Time" of the mobile phone using "J2ME"?

Tags: java

I'm developing a mobile application using `J2ME` for a configuration `CLDC-MIDP2.0`.

In my mobile application, I need to make the user should able to adjust the `Date` and `Time` settings of mobile.

Here I'm using "DateField" to get the date from the user, but I cannot set or change the mobile phone's `Date` and `Time`.

So please help me.How to change the `Date` and `Time` of the mobile phone using `J2ME`. Here I'm using **Nokia c2-00** mobile is for testing. It is "S40" device.

Ideas of all are welcome.

Comment: Not sure if this is OT or not. I *think* it would be better on SO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mobiles internal time cannot be changed by Java, because of security features which dont allow access to the native operations. See this [link](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Discussion/showthread.php?13343-How-can-I-set-system-time-in-mobile-using-J2ME)